# Encryption and decryption of video file in android

Tags: android, encryption

Can anyone please tell me how to encrypt video file while downloading from the server and decrypt it while playing inside the app? please help. thank you.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. What do you need to do? How does it need to be encrypted?

Comment: i want to encrypt video file that no one can access it from the outside the app. and after the downloading it only play in the app.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code-request site. Nor a tutorial place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) and [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) for encryption and decryption of file in android.

There are two ways through which you can achieve your goal

Download a file and encrypt it, when you want to play that file decry-pt it in a temporary file and play it.

if you want to play encrypted file on the fly (not decrypting it in a temp file) then you can use [Libmedia](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/) library. It streams encrypted file on local host and play it from there

Comment: I need to decrypt on demand like in live video streaming, do you have a hint?