# Is there any video loader library like there is image library like image loaders that can load videos faster

Tags: android, security, video, encryption

I am developing app that has a feature like "save offline" feature in youtube,
i have encrypted videos with cipher and saved it inside files folder.
now when i retrieve the videos it takes time to decrypt back and to show to users.
so is there any library or is there something else that can make my encrypt-decrypt process faster or load videos instantly that use have saved offline.

Comment: "so is there any library or is there something else that can make my encrypt-decrypt process faster" -- we have no idea what your "encrypt-decrypt process" is, and so we cannot comment on how to make it faster. "or load videos instantly that use have saved offline" -- while there are media playback libraries (e.g, ExoPlayer, libVLC), most likely they will not handle some modified version of a video file, such as one using your encryption approach.

Comment: i have used cipher input stream to encrypt-decrypt my video by getting inspired by these question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426380/encryption-and-decryption-of-video-file-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try exoplayer library. this library has lots of features which can be useful. you can play a complete playlist. etc.

exoPlayer supports features like Dynamic adaptive streaming over HTTP (DASH), SmoothStreaming and Common Encryption, which are not supported by MediaPlayer. It's designed to be easy to customize and extend.

Git hub Repository: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

android developer: [Android official documanetaion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)

Comment: Good one Maaz! ;)